# Word 2013's Quick Parts > Document Property menu is greyed out

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I want to insert a Publish Date field in my document footer but the ribbon bar's INSERT > Quick Parts > Document Property menu is greyed out / disabled. How to get it to work?

Answer (score 4):

If the document is in Compatibility Mode that menu will be greyed out (which probably means it was originally created in an old version of Word). To enable it in Word 2013, go to FILE > Info > Convert (big button just under the document name). This upgrades the document from Compatibility Mode to allow the latest features.

Now the Quick Parts > Document Property will be available.

Answer (score 0):

In Word 2010, you'll need to save the document as a .docm.

I was also told that it may also need versioning enabled in the sharepoint site.